# passing parameters from 2 select queries to another select query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to compare two different values of the same column in a select query.
This is my code, and I'm only passing one value (from the nearest select query). Can you help me out how can I pass the second value from the other query? 
to make it a bit more clear, I want to compare the startTime with endTime=null (the time our user logged in to our website and didn't finish an order) to the startTime with endTime!=null (user logged in and registered an order).

```
SELECT
  notFinished,
  finished,
  DATEDIFF(notFinished, finished) as dateDifference,
  emailAddress,
  phone,
  __key__.id
FROM  (
  SELECT
    startTime AS finished
  FROM
    [datastore_dump.Orders]
  WHERE
    emailAddress IN (
    SELECT
      emailAddress
    FROM
      [datastore_dump.Orders]
    WHERE
      endTime IS NULL)
    AND endTime IS NOT NULL and emailAddress is not null ),
(
  SELECT
    emailAddress,
    phone,
    __key__.id,
    startTime AS notFinished
  FROM
    [datastore_dump.Orders]
  WHERE
    endTime IS NULL)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider below logic:

```
SELECT
  emailAddress, startTime, endTime, DATEDIFF(endTime, startTime) AS daysDifference
FROM (
  SELECT
    emailAddress, startTime, endTime, status,
    LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY emailAddress ORDER BY startTime) AS prevStatus
  FROM (
    SELECT
      emailAddress, startTime, endTime,
      IF(endTime IS NULL, "not-finished", "finished") AS status
    FROM [datastore_dump.Orders]
  )
)
WHERE status = "finished"
AND prevStatus = "not-finished"
```

what it does is:
1. qualifies status of each record as `finished` or `not-finished` based on `endTime`
2. finds previous status for each record - `prevStatus`
3. for the records with status finished and previous status not-finished - calculated diff

Hope this is close to what you asked

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really helpful. Just one thing which I still dont understand, how can I get the startTime of the status= not_finished? I want to know if the user finished the shopping later that day or couple of  days later.  thats why I want to use the date difference for startTime with endTime null, and startTime with endTime not null.

Comment: in `IF(endTime IS NULL, "not-finished", "finished") AS status` - status is set to `not-finished` if endTime IS NULL as per how it defined in your question

Comment: I guess I vote it Up now. it just goes to 1, right? Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This type of logic is easier to express in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options") using a `WITH` clause. To get you started, you might want something like this:

```
WITH CompletedOrders AS (
  SELECT
    startTime AS finished
  FROM
    datastore_dump.Orders
  WHERE
    emailAddress IN (
    SELECT
      emailAddress
    FROM
      datastore_dump.Orders
    WHERE
      endTime IS NULL)
    AND endTime IS NOT NULL and emailAddress IS NOT NULL
), IncompleteOrders AS (
  SELECT
    emailAddress,
    phone,
    __key__.id,
    startTime AS notFinished
  FROM
    datastore_dump.Orders
  WHERE
    endTime IS NULL)
SELECT ...
```

As a working example, you can try:

```
WITH Orders AS (
  SELECT 'foo@example.com' AS email, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS time
  UNION ALL SELECT 'bar@example.com' AS email, NULL AS time
  UNION ALL SELECT
    'baz@example.com',
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS time),
CompletedOrders AS (
  SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE time IS NOT NULL),
IncompleteOrders AS (
  SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE time IS NULL)
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CompletedOrders) AS completed_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IncompleteOrders) AS incomplete_count;
+-----------------+------------------+
| completed_count | incomplete_count |
+-----------------+------------------+
|               2 |                1 |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!